# Menu dismissal problem - depends on menu content

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location

My app needs to track the user's location but each time my `locationManager` sends a location update, it dismisses a toolbar menu (if it is displayed). The odd thing is that if the menu buttons have empty actions or just a print statement then all is fine but as soon as a method is put in there it dismisses upon the next UI update.

iOS: 17.0

Xcode: Version 15.0 beta 3

Background Modes: Location updates

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description = You are being watched!

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DetectHelpApp: App {

    var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(locationManager)
        }
    }
}

import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(LocationManager.self) var locationManager

    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.556000, longitude: -0.279511), latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
                UserAnnotation()
            }
            .onChange(of: locationManager.lastLocation) { oldValue, newValue in
                print(locationManager.lastLocation)
                withAnimation() {
                    cameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: newValue.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000))
                }
            } // onChange - end
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Menu("Menu") {
                        Button("Start") { help() /*print("Start")*/ } // <-- *** HERE ***
                        Button("Resume") { print("Resume") }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Scooby Doo")
        }
    }

    func help() { }
}

import CoreLocation
import Observation

@Observable
final class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var lastLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 51.556000, longitude: -0.279511)

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    init(dog: String = "") {
        super.init()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 2
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Ensure we have an actual location in the update.
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }

        lastLocation = location // Our published CLLocation.
    }
}
```